# can walking practice really cure people who walk pigeon toed?

Tags: posture, walking, gait-walk-abnormalities, intoeing-pigeon-toe-foot

and is this true in all cases? cause i have been pigeon toed all my life, and lately people have started commenting on it so much that it's starting to bother me. About 10 years ago when i was in high school my dad made me train myself to walk correctly, but I feel like all that ever did was teach me to walk correctly when I"m focusing on it.

7 years after that people started commenting on it again, so I cried and went back to practicing again, but I don't know whether it helped any.

I'm in Korea now, and Korean care about appearances a lot more so basically everyone everywhere comments on it, so i'm extremely self-conscious.  However, lately I've been wondering if I should be looking at surgery rather than more practice.

however, being in Korea, I also think talking to the doctors will be difficult, and I want to know some likely causes of pigeon-toed walking in adults.